# Spark Broadcast variables life time

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am running a spark streaming job, as part of it I am creating multiple broadcast variables.

So, I have two questions about it.
1. Is there any function which can give a list of all the broadcasted variables like spark.getPersistentRDDs which lists all the persisted RDD.
2. If we do not destroy the Spark broadcast variables, would they be delete by Spark after they have not been used for a certain period of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Spark does not provide function to list all the broadcasted variables like getPersistentRDDs but one alternative solution is, whenever broadcast variable is created, store it in list/queue for future reference.
2. Spark has ContextCleaner which runs on periodic interval to delete broadcast variable if it is not being used.
   https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ContextCleaner.scala#L233

Comment: So, is there any way to trigger the ContextClear? If not do you know how often it is triggered by the Spark?

Also, the broadcast variables are first created in Driver Memory right. Which part of the memory do they use? Heap memory or non-heap memory?

Comment: 1. Context cleaner is private class so no way to access it .   
2. It is created immediately once sparkContext is created and stopped when sparkContext is stopped. It keeps running in infinite loop . 
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ContextCleaner.scala#L178 .       
It maintains weak reference for each RDD/Broadcast_variable and check whenever reference goes out of scope of application, it initiates cleanup task.     
3. Not sure